# python: How to count the elements of a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a DataFrame named `a`. I want to count the element of each row.

```
import numpy as np
a=pd.DataFrame({'A1':['financial','game','game'],'A2':['social','food','sport'],'A3':['social','sport','game']})
```

`Input:`

```
          A1      A2      A3
0  financial  social  social
1       game    food   sport
2       game   sport    game
```

`Expected:`

```
    financial  food  game  social  sport
0          1      0     0       2      0
1          0      1     1       0      1
2          0      0     2       0      1
```

Hopefully for help, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `sum`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(a, prefix_sep='', prefix='').sum(axis=1, level=0)
print (df)
   financial  game  food  social  sport
0          1     0     0       2      0
1          0     1     1       0      1
2          0     2     0       0      1
```

Or [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = a.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
   financial  food  game  social  sport
0          1     0     0       2      0
1          0     1     1       0      1
2          0     0     2       0      1
```