# How to count the frequency of the elements in a dataframe's row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data frame like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['pqr', 'abc', 'pqr', 'NULL', 'NULL']], 
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])

  col1 col2 col3  col4  col5
0  pqr  abc  pqr  NULL  NULL
```

Desired output:

```
code count
pqr   2
abc   1
```

How can I do to get above in Python?

I have tried with `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']).count().reset_index()
```

I didn't get desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: How to count the elements of a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331557/python-how-to-count-the-elements-of-a-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `df`:

```
>>> df

  col1 col2 col3  col4  col5
0  pqr  abc  pqr   NaN   NaN
```

You can use `stack()` and `value_counts()`:

```
df.stack().value_counts().reset_index().\
    rename({'index':'code',
            0:'count'},axis=1)
```

Prints:

```
  code  count
0  pqr      2
1  abc      1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the occurences **over** the dataframe -

```
df.loc[0:(length(df.index)-1)].stack().to_frame()[0].value_counts()
```

To get occurences over any **row i** -

```
df.loc[i].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value_counts` and drop `NULL`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['pqr', 'abc', 'pqr', 'NULL', 'NULL']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])

counts = df.T.value_counts()
counts.index.rename('code', inplace=True)
counts.sort_index(inplace=True)  # avoids warning by pandas about dropping from unsorted index
counts = counts.drop('NULL')
counts = pd.DataFrame(counts, columns=['count'])

print(counts)
```

out:

```
      count
code       
pqr       2
abc       1
```